# Data file (dll) not deployed with ClickOnce

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce, libraries

I've a winform app deployed with ClickOnce. It has some librarys, stored in a subfolder (AppRoot\Apps), that I've marked with Datafile status in the publishing properties, and the publication of the application works allright.
But when the application is deploying, all of the libraries deploy ok but one, and I can't now why.

Anyone can help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of files are they, and why are you deploying them as data files?

If they are assemblies that you have references to, do your references point to the assemblies in the folder? You should do this: Put the files in the folder. For properties, set "Build Action" to "None" and set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Do not copy". Delete existing references. Re-add each reference, and browse to the assembly in that folder in the project. On the reference, set "copy local" to true.

If they are assemblies that you do not have references to, just set the build action to "Content" and set "copy to output directory" to "copy always".  This is how data files should be set as well.

If you mess around with the settings in Application Files, be aware that if you set them to be Data, and they have a file extension of XML, SDF, MDB, etc., they will be deployed to the ApplicationDeployment.DataDirectory folder, not to the same folder as the executable and other files. You can override this by changing it from Data to Include(Required) in the Application Files dialog.